# How to get value of date filed using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How to get the value of date field using selenium ?

Eg: [date is 08/12/2015 is already selected then how to select that value using selenium web driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKAgI.png)

Comment: give html snippet example rather than image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this to fetch the value inside the element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("input_name"));
String elementval = element.getAttribute("value");
```